# Migrating from Neo4j to Grakn

Tags: neo4j, cypher, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I'm in the process of migrating a neo4j database into Grakn for genomics and biological data, I have the files in CSV for this but I need to an ETL Tool for solving this problem in the simplest way.

I am following this template Python migrator:
https://blog.grakn.ai/loading-data-and-querying-knowledge-from-a-grakn-knowledge-graph-using-the-python-client-b764a476cda8

Am I correct in thinking this way -

- Do nodes map to entities?
- Do edges in neo4j map to relationships in Grakn?
- Do labels map to attributes?

Answer (score 3):

While it is possible to use a direct mapping of the property-graph model to the entity-relationship model (used by Grakn), it is highly likely that limitations and shortcomings of the property graph model will be transferred. This is why Grakn does not provide or encourage a completely general migration tool. Every Grakn knowledge graph should be powered by a thought-out model (ie. schema) that is tailored to the intended domain.

To outline how one can easily (re)model a dataset in Grakn, the key is to create a schema that closely resembles how we perceive data in the real world in terms of things and their interactions. This easily maps onto the Entity-Relationship-Attribute model Grakn uses. It is common to iterate several times before settling on the final schema (though it can always be extended later).

Then we can:

- ask intuitive questions (in the form of Graql queries) - using the defined Entities/Relationships/Attributes that map closely to our mental model
- build an intelligent database that is capable of reasoning over data the same way we do, by adding logical, deductive rules that apply in our domain

I encourage to you check out this [blog post](https://blog.grakn.ai/the-challenges-of-working-with-a-graph-database-2a5f9a7c903b) on the challenges of working with graph databases, and for any domain specific modeling questions head over to the Grakn [community forum](https://discuss.grakn.ai/).

Good luck and welcome to Grakn!

Answer (score 0):

If you map your property graph directly to GRAKN, you will end up with relations that are most likely named as verbs connecting only two objects (one of which will appear to be a subject and the other an object). GRAKN will be fine with this, but as mentioned previously, may make leveraging all the goodness in GRAKN more difficult. In particular, converting existing graph structures to hyperedges may take some significant reengineering. But the good news is that the ETL would be straightforward.

A better solution would be to define your ideal schema first in GRAKN (taking advantage of hyperedges), then fashion an ETL to populate the schema. In such a case, the ETL might be simple or complex. It would depend on how complex your original data was and how complex the new schema was.